# Save jquery object that has been inserted into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using jQuery to add a tag icon into the DOM. I want it to be inserted with opacity 0 and then appear with `animate()` immediately after that.

Currently I am inserting it like this:

```
$('.tag_boxes').append("<span class='tag_box' data-title='"+word+"'>"+word+"<a class='remove_tag'>x</a></span>");
```

Is there a way to cache this `<span>` tag as a jQuery object immediately with this operation? So that I can call animate on the next line. Something like:

```
var s = $('.tag_boxes').append("<span class='tag_box' data-title='"+word+"'>"+word+"<a class='remove_tag'>x</a></span>");
s.animate({'opacity':1});
```

There might not be a solution using `append()` but is there another function that can do it?

I know that I can give the tag an ID and then access it with jQuery, but I suspect doing that will query the DOM and look for that element all over again (correct me if i'm wrong) - I would prefer to use the most efficent solution if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a jQuery object from the span HTML:

```
var s = $("<span class='tag_box' data-title='"+word+"'>"+word+"<a class='remove_tag'>x</a></span>");
$('.tag_boxes').append(s);

s.animate({'opacity':1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be doing it with CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes show_tag_box {
   0% { opacity: 0; }
   100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.tag_box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-animation: show_tag_box 500ms;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1zotk5j/1/). Don't forget browser prefixes.

Comment: Hey ostrgard. I was more wondering about the caching operation in general than for this specific purpose. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Either way, you're welcome. I learned something from MrCode's answer as well!